# Link should always open in a single and same window (if already opened) - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, window, link-to

In my Rails application, I have a link which would be targeted to another window with a URL having different parameters (not always , can be the same parameters also) at different timings. Say, for e.g., link 'test'.

If I click on it for first time, it would open in another window with a specific URL along with some parameters. Then if I again click on the link, it should open in the already opened window. Is there any rails way/any other way for achieving it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`target: "_blank"`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_target.asp) for this:

```
<%= link_to "link", link_path, target: "blank" %>
```

Comment: This will open in another window for sure. But, if we click on the link multiple times, will it redirect to the already opened window rather than opening another window?

Comment: let me check and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: I tested the link you have provided. It just opens in a new tab always.

Comment: What browser you using? Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: In both I've checked. Both have the same result.

Comment: Yes, we use it in Chrome & it loads up a new tab if you click the link once, and refreshes the tab if you use it again? I thought it may be a cross-browser issue, but not!